# Testing a function that validates name

Tags: python

How do I write multiple test cases for a single function. I want the functions to essentially iterate through a bunch of tests and then return a boolean or answer saying that the function has passed these tests.

def test_valid01():

```
name = 'jack'
expected = True
assert is_valid_name(name) == expected, "is_valid_name has failed."
test1 = True
```

this is an example of one of my functions testing another function.

Answer (score 1):

A way that you could test various tests for the is_valid_name() function:

```
def assert_test_valid(name, expected_value):
    assert is_valid_name(name) == expected_value, f"is_valid_name has failed for {name}" # allows identification of which test failed
    
def test_valid_all():
    test_responses = { # the input and the expected response
        'jack': True,
    }
    for key, value in test_responses.items(): # to go through all of the responses that you would like to test
        assert_test_valid(key, value)
```